# Monitoring Facebook groups for keywords

Tags: monitoring, facebook

- I want to **monitor** (24/7) two Facebook groups I am a member of. Any time there will be a new post containing the key word I am after I will be notified (via email preferably).
- I want to be able to use **different keywords per group**
- and to be able to use **wild cards**. So for example `transfer*` will match

  - transfer
  - transferred
  - transferring

would anyone know if such application (web,cloud based) exists? Something that would meet above criteria? Free or open source.

Comment: I don't know if this still works with Facebook well after recent rule changes, but you could look at a service like [Liferaft](http://liferaftinc.com/) that lets you monitor activity on social media sites and setup triggers and the like.  I haven't really tried to do what you're describing with it though, so I don't know if it would really do that.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please specify: what OS shall that application run on (or should it be a web-app)? What kind of notifications do you want (alarm tone, mail, SMS, …)? When it comes to paid apps, what's your budget limitation?

Comment: @izzy: I updated my question. I am looking for 24/7 platform that would trigger a notification (email preferably) when set keyword was posted in specified fb group.

Comment: I'm out anyway (Facebook, WhatsApp & Co are on my blacklist) – but this is at least borderline here. Remember SR is about recommending *software*, not services/providers (see e.g. [Is requesting a service on-topic?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2627/185)). But as I never got the line where the border is running, I won't throw a vote – especially not into unfamiliar terrain :)

Comment: @izzy so where to ask? I am coming from web apps. Got the same response there ....

Comment: As I wrote, Radek, I'm not throwing in a vote here – it's not my area of expertise. And I didn't say it's off-topic here, just borderline. So as long as nobody objects and throws "votes to close" (until now, noone has), let it stay here. Sorry that I cannot be of better help.